# prolog syntax problem

Tags: operators, prolog

I can't distinguish these symbols:

`=` and `=:=`

`\=` and `=\=`

`[X,Y]` and `[X|Y]`

What’s the difference ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the comparison operators (`=`, `=:=`, `\=`, `=\=`):

- `=` succeeds if the terms [unify](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/prologdict.html#unification) (basically, if they're bound together)
- `=:=` succeeds if the values of the terms are equal (should be equivalent to `=` if you're dealing with numbers, I believe)
- `\=` is the negation of `=`
- `=\=` is the negation of `=:=`

For more info about these operators and more, see [this page](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/prologdict.html#comparison).

For the list operators, `[X|Y]` is a way to refer to a list where `X` is the first element and `Y` is the list of the remaining elements.  `[X, Y]` is just another way to refer to this, but it limits `Y` to being a single element, instead of possibly a whole list of them.  For more info, see [this section of the same page](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/prologdict.html#list).